# How to synchronize two sqlite databases

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, synchronization, wt

I have two identical sqlite databases from the structure side. I want to synchronize the data between the two but I need to keep some tables away from the synchronization.

Is there any library can do that or do I have to do it myself?

P.S. I'm using C++/Wt

Comment: I read about [symmetricds](http://www.symmetricds.org/) but I'm not sure what if works for the above request

Comment: I have seen two other frameworks: https://ampliapps.com/sqlite-sync/ and http://litesync.io/